# How to access URL segment(s) in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

So let's say we have the following url:

```
http://example.com/shops/map/search
```

I want to access the second segment (map) and check its value.
How can I achieve this in Express? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, [route parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) can be used for that. Do you have any relevant code you can share?

Comment: I am using route parameters when I want to access an entity by id for example. However in my case I just need to know if the second segment is map or list. They both are hard-coded. Is my question clearer now?

Comment: Better, but not completely. If they're hard-coded / constants, is there a reason the route handler can't be aware of the same constant? Are you reusing a single handler for both routes?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Correct, I am trying to avoid creating a new handler because the code changes just slightly and I don't want to duplicate code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the url segments by splitting  the url into an array.
Like this:

```
let requestSegments = req.path.split('/');
```

Answer (score 13):

you have to configure your express routes to accept url segments.

```
app.get('/shops/:type/search', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

For a request like this
 http://example.com/shops/map/search

req.params will contain required URL segment.

```
Request URL: http://example.com/shops/map/search
req.params: { "type": "map" }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a route parameters with a constant set of values.

Express uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) to parse the strings you provide for routes. That package [permits providing a custom pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#custom-match-parameters) with a parameter to limit the values that can be matched.

```
app.get('/shops/:kind(list|map)/search', searchShops);
```

The contents of the parenthesis, `(...)`, are a partial RegExp pattern, in this case equivalent to:

```
/(?:list|map)/
# within a non-capturing group, match an alternative of either "list" or "map" literally
```

Then, within `searchShops`, you can determine which value was given with `req.params`:

```
function searchShops(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.kind); // 'list' or 'map'
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can leave the parameter open, checking the value within the handler, and invoke [`next('route')`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD) when the value isn't acceptable:

```
app.get('/shops/:kind/search', searchShops);

var searchKinds = ['list', 'map'];

function searchShops(req, res, next) {
    if (!searchKinds.includes(req.params.kind)) return next('route');

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answer does the job, but leaves you with an empty element in the array. I'd use the following slight variation to solve this too.

```
let requestSegments = req.path.split('/').filter((s) => { return s !== ''});
```